# Design a Voltmeter using BJT

Tags: bjt, voltmeter

How to design a voltmeter using BJT and minimal other components to measure between 0-5V in 10 different steps(i.e 0-0.5,0.5-1,so on).Explain its working to.

Comment: you mean a window detector? or using the LEDbar chip? do some more homework

Comment: no not talking about window detector but I do not have any idea about the answer of the question.

Comment: OK I have no idea where you got this requirement without specs for output. Seriously. your question is vague.

Comment: You want us to do your homework assignments? This is not the right place. You didn't show any effort at all.

Comment: If you have no idea  how a voltmeter works or why such non standard ranges , something is missing in you or "homework question" (-1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faXUuq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: please can you explain its working

Comment: Reminds me a lot of the of the MC1496.

Comment: @AMANKUMAR This is your homework. The above circuit goes back into the 1960s. And it is as important to be comfortable with as is the long-tailed pair, probably. Focus on what is set up at Q4 and Q5 and what happens at R5 when the base voltage of Q1 is raised above the base voltage at Q2; and how that impacts the collector currents of Q1 and Q2. It should become obvious at that point.

Comment: Just a note: The differences in current densities in Q1 and Q2 caused by a base voltage difference will act *as if* \$r_e\$ exists at the tip of the Q1 and Q2 emitters for computing the current in R5 when ignoring the current density difference. This suggests about a -5% gain error with R12's setting and the choice of R5. It helps to increase R5 to reduce the effect, but then that drops the voltage gain seen at VM1. Nice, direct answer. I like it.

Comment: There is also a minor non-linearity; a duplicate set of (4) bipolars, running at only 10% of the 10mA I tossed out there, with collectors crossing over, will reduce that non-linearity. Were I to use this, I'd run at the 1mA or 100uA level, and perhaps use Darlingtons for inputs. I suspect the teacher has in mind a one-transistor solution, using various resistors to in essence perform level-shifting.